# How to monitor a file on Google Drive and get notified when changes to this file have been made in an android application

Tags: android, google-drive-api, gson, android-syncadapter

How can I monitor a file on Google Drive in the most efficient way in my android Application? I prefer not to use a polling mechanism because of the possible unneeded data traffic involved.

On the Google developers site I found the following information: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/watch
But I cannot find any examples where this has been applied (e.g. how to use the channel, how to integrate this in a sync adapter etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch notifications can only be received by web hooks at the moment, we're going to be extending the notifications to the mobile environments soon. For now, you need to poll `files.get` to see if there are any changes.

Comment: You could have a server that receives such pushes and then forwards it to your app. But maybe better wait for api support on mobile.

Comment: @Burcu Dogan can i receive any notification or update in my android application that there is a list of files are uploaded onto my google drive account , if possible can you please show me how to do that??

Comment: Any update on this, for mobile environments? How can we tell if this gets implemented?

Answer (score 0):

With [Google Play services 4.3](http://android-developers.blogspot.gr/2014/03/google-play-services-43.html) we can now register callbacks to be notified when a file changes.

Comment: I tried the demo app in the Google play services and checked notifications on file change but it is not showing the notification.How can i achieve this?

Comment: Hmm I can't answer that. I still haven't founnd the time to implement the new API. I will edit my comment if I find something helpful.